# Suppress PyCharm warning when a variable is assigned as None in init method

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm for python coding. In a class, I have few fields, whose value will not be passed when instantiating the class, but will be set later. So, in `__init__()` method, I'm setting their values to be `None`. Also, to utilize PyCharm auto code completion, I'm specifying the data-type of these fields.

```
class SelectFrame():
    index_data: pandas.DataFrame
    index_filepath: Path

    def __init__(self):
        self.index_data = None
        self.index_filepath = None
```

But with this, PyCharm is giving a warning `Expected Type 'DataFrame', got 'None' instead`. How can I remove this warning?

Note: I don't want to suppress the TypeChecker warning altogether, neither do I want to put the comment `# noinspection PyTypeChecker` everywhere I use such code. My question is
**Is the None initialization correct? Or is there a better way to initialize and avoid the warning?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The None initialization is correct (unless you can know it during construction) but you declared index_data as pandas.DataFrame and **None is not  pandas.DataFrame** so it warns you.

You should enhance the type declaration to include None as well by using **Optional**.

```
from typing import Optional

class SelectFrame():
    index_data: Optional[pandas.DataFrame]
    index_filepath: Optional[Path]

    def __init__(self):
        self.index_data = None
        self.index_filepath = None
```

Comment: Does PyCharm have an equivalent to the MyPy --no-strict-optional setting? I find it really annoying to have to use `Optional` everywhere and would rather `None` were always treated by PyCharm as valid in every situation.

Do you know if there's a setting buried somewhere deep I haven't seen or else some workaround that doesn't involve disabling the type checker inspection or using # `noinspection PyTypeChecker` everywhere?

Comment: Hi @matthewgdv, I have the exact same question. Did you already find a solution?